# Graphics debugging in MSVC 2017 - An error occured. Playback of your application may be incomplete

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, pixel-shader

I successfully recorded a DX11 diag session once. When running it the second and any further time, when I click on a frame I get this error:

> An error occured. Playback of your application may be incomplete. (HRESULT = 0x00630000) "Unknown error (0x00630000)"

I capture frames programmatically, using the code [shown here in Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/graphics/walkthrough-capturing-graphics-information-programmatically?view=vs-2019). It worked before with other shaders as well as the one I'm debugging now.

I have a RAII class for the debugging:

```
class GPUBlock
{
public:
  GPUBlock() : _startResult(DXGIGetDebugInterface1(0, __uuidof(_directXAnalysis), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&_directXAnalysis)))
  {
    if (debugInitialized())
      _directXAnalysis->BeginCapture();
  }

  ~GPUBlock()
  {
    if (debugInitialized())
      _directXAnalysis->EndCapture();
  }

  bool debugInitialized() const { return _directXAnalysis && !FAILED(_startResult); }
private:
  IDXGraphicsAnalysis* _directXAnalysis = nullptr;
  HRESULT _startResult = OLE_E_BLANK;
};
```

Used as:

```
{
    Debug::GPUBlock debugGPUplease;
    DoGPUWork();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you must click the "Stop collection" button. If you end the debugging this way, the logs will work just fine.

[image]

It is not clear why it worked without it before, but it was probably luck and not normal behaviour.

Also, this error will happen if `BeginCapture()` and `EndCapture()` are called at inappropriate moments. You can't just place them wherever! You need to capture the entirety of the GPU operation, including the setup.

Comment: Hi Tomas, thanks for sharing your solution and you can consider marking it as answer. SO that other members with similar issue could easily find your workaround. Thx:)